# How to pursue my IT career in the Philippines?

Tags: working-visas, indian-citizens, philippines

I am a software developer with a year of experience in **Full Stack Web Development** and **Android Development**. Because of some reasons, I wish to travel to the **Philippines** and work there. I have applied for many companies but I am being rejected on the grounds of visa sponsorship.
My question here concerns what all should I do to get a job there so that I can pursue my career in the Philippines.

I just need to know slight about expats in the Philippines, the companies open to expats and what all are the top skills and requirements needed to work there and be successful.
Thank you.

Comment: That's quite the broad question. Could you perhaps elaborate (as per the [help]) on specific problems fast? "What should I do" could cover things from working on open source, getting a degree, learning a language, getting more online experience, tools/stacks to learn.  It's just too broad in its present format.

Answer (score 1):

If no Philippine company will sponsor you under 'pre arranged employment', do you have enough capital to enter as a businessman?
If your reasons (not stated in your post) to go there are to do with family, can the family member either recommend you to an employer, or could you get a spouse visa?

Comment: No reasons for a family. And I am just into professionalism so I cannot arrange for pre arranged employment. Sorry about that.